# Is a ''zu'' missing in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure, verb-usage, infinitive, gerund

I read a tweet which is a comment about some news about taxing tampons and I couldn't understand the last part because there are 2 verbs (not modal and not connected with *zu* or something).

> Ja endlich können sich nun auch die ärmsten Tampons leisten und endlich das ständige Binden waschen sparen.

Comment: The question is rather if there should be another "sich".

Comment: Die armen Tampons!

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is correct.

> Ja endlich können sich nun auch die Ärmsten Tampons leisten und endlich *das ständige Bindenwaschen* sparen.

The verbs in both parts of the sentences are *können leisten* and *[können] sparen*

The second verb in the sentence *waschen* is only a nominalisation of the verb, which comes in infinitive form. There are generally two types in nominalisation, the ones with "zu" and those without. [Here](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/infinitivsaetze.html) are many examples.

Comment: "The sentence is correct." No, it is not. It is "die Ärmsten" and "Bindenwaschen".

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a mistake in this sentence, which might be overlooked by native speakers but confuses non-natives. Correctly it would be:

> Ja endlich können sich nun auch die ärmsten Tampons leisten und endlich das ständige **Bindenwaschen** sparen.

Bindenwaschen as a nominalistation has to be written together and with an upper case letter.

When you take a look at *das Binden waschen sparen* the article *das* refers to *waschen*: 
She wants to spair the washing of the saintary pads.

And as you might know, every word addressed with an article has to be written in capital. 
But now comes the connection betwen *waschen* und *Binden*. If you translate the sentence above into german again it woudl be: 
*Sie möchte das Waschen der Binden sparen*

Now you can "merge" the two nouns *Waschen **der** Binden* into *Bindenwaschen*

So in conclusion the writer was just sloppy and filled in an additional Spacebar which makes the nominalisation appear as a noun and a verb without connection

Comment: Actually there are two (orthographic) mistakes (Ärmsten needs the upper-case initial).